# session.getAttribute return null for Chrome Browser. (Servlet)

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to create a plugin for Atlassian JIRA. I have a Java servlet that calls a JSP page in my project. In the servlet, It should return an object. But an error occurred due to that servlet returning null instead of the expected result. This only happens in the **Chrome browser**. I have tested this in Firefox, Microsoft Edge, safari browsers, this is working fine for them and return the expected output.

code as follows. (**Session.java**)

```
public static <T> T get(final HttpServeletRequest request, final String key) {

   final HttpSession session = request.getSession();
   final Object ImpObj = session.getAttribute(key);

   if(ImpObj == null) {
      return null;
   }

   try {
     return (T) ImpObj;
   } catch(final Exception e) {
     return null;
   }
}
```

Inside my class files, I'm calling above Session.java file like this

```
ImportFlawsObject impFlwObj = Session.get(request, "FLAW_IMPORTER");
```

I have debugged the code and try to find the root cause, what happened was in the **Chrome browser**, each time `session.getAttribute(key)` return **null**. An issue occurred from here.

It is really hard to find a solution for this, Appreciate your suggestions and it will help me to find a better solution for this.

Comment: When you're trying to get the `attribute`, you must be setting it somewhere or it's something in-built? If you're setting this attribute at browser, may be in cookies or local storage, did you check if it's getting stored there?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution that worked for me. My website is inside an iframe that belongs to a third party, this problem in my case was caused because cookies were blocked on my iframe site. You can add the site to your whitelist and solve the problem, although the funny thing is that in firefox and edge this is not necessary.